# I'm trying to compile my java project in command prompt and it's giving me these errors

Tags: java, command-prompt

[these are the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eIHu.jpg)

from this point I'm getting the error

```
public ArrayList<DatabasePayroll> getDbPList() {
    ArrayList<DatabasePayroll> dbPList = new ArrayList<DatabasePayroll>();
    Connection connection = getConnection();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM `salary sheet`";
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        st = connection.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        DatabasePayroll databasePayroll;
        while (rs.next()) {
            databasePayroll = new DatabasePayroll(rs.getInt("Num"), rs.getString("Name"), rs.getDate("LastPaymentDate"), rs.getString("Site"), rs.getString("Designation"), rs.getFloat("SalaryBalance"), rs.getFloat("PerDay"), rs.getFloat("Days"), rs.getFloat("Salary"), rs.getFloat("OTHours"), rs.getFloat("OTRate"), rs.getDouble("OT"), rs.getFloat("Allowance"), rs.getDouble("GrossSalary"), rs.getFloat("Advance"), rs.getFloat("Loan"), rs.getDouble("NetSalary"), rs.getDouble("RequestedAmount"), rs.getString("Status"));
            dbPList.add(databasePayroll);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dbPList;
}
```

I'm using import java.util.ArrayList; package.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] and include the errors *in the question*. (I suspect the problem is that you're compiling only part of your code and expecting the compiler to find the other classes, but without compiling from the package root...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like compilation issue.Make sure your DatabasePayroll class is properly imported. If that comes from an external jar then add that jar in your build path. Better use a java IDE like eclipse which simplifies compilation,debugging, many others.